# ASP.NET MVC 5 - References vs bin folders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2013, based on another project I have been given by somebody significantly more experienced than me. In his project, there is a `References` folder, with references to System, System.Core etc., together with third-party libraries. However, this folder does not exist by default in my new ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Instead, I have a folder called `bin`, which looks similar to `References`, and I can add references to dlls. What is the difference between the `References` and `bin` folders? Why does his project have one, and mine has the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your references 'folder' are assemblies (DLLs) that are referenced by your project. The reference is held in text in the project file.

The bin folder is used for compilation of your project. At compile time, the references in the project file are resolved (located for use by your project when it's running). This may be copying them from another location on disk, downloading a nuget package or using a version from the GAC. If the assembly is going to be copied down from another location it will be copied into the bin folder where all the files necessary for the application to run are stored.

UPDATE:

A different project type had been added and hence the references folder was not visible. Adding an ASP.NET Web Project into the solution solved this.

Comment: Thanks. But why does my project not have a References folder by default?

Comment: Because the web project you are using references a number of DLLs\assemblies by default. If you open it up it will reference things like System.Web or Microsoft.Owin. These are all assemblies built by Microsoft or the community that have basic functionality that your project needs to work out of the box from creation. Without them your project won't work immediately. You may be able to remove some of them but I wouldn't whilst you don't understand them.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot see the References folder at all. So if I want to add a reference to a third-party dll, then how can I check that it has worked if I cannot see the References folder?

Comment: Right click on the project you want to add a reference to. Select Add reference. select either A file from the GAC (Assemblies), a project from your open solution (Solution), a COM dll (basically old style or C DLLs etc) or browse to a physical DLL file. When you have selected one of these and hit OK you should see the References folder added with the name of the thing you added inside. Try one from the Assemblies tab. Adding one shouldn't break anything.

Comment: I did try this already: Right-click on my project, then Add->Reference->Browse, then selected a dll from my third-party library. This did not show the References folder, but instead added this dll to the bin folder. So the bin folder has items such as Microsoft.Owin.dll, System.Web.Mvc.dll, together with this third-party dll I have just added. But there is still no References folder in the Solution Explorer!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know what the issue is without looking at what you have. If you can build the solution \ run it without any errors you don't have to worry about anything. Have a read from MSDN about [Managing References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51197/discussion-between-sarin-and-karnivaurus)

Comment: This is a notable difference between Web Site projects and Web Application projects.  Web Site uses bin directly because it doesn't have a project file in which to track references; Web Application keeps references in the *proj file, and then copies them to bin during build.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015:

> File >> New >> Project (Web Application)

A Project will have a References node when viewed through Solution Explorer in the IDE. If viewed with a file explorer (Windows Explorer) there is no Reference folder. References are stored in the project (csproj or vbproj) file using plain xml/text.

> File >> New >> Web Site

A Web site does not have the References node nor a project file. In Solution Explorer right-click on the Bin folder or the root node to add References. References can be seen in the Property Pages (right-click root node).